# FreeOPC won't start in boot

Tags: python, opc

I'm new on Python and Raspberry world, so excuse my ignorance :)

i have sucessfuly installed and run OPC server on a raspberry using Python.
But when i have made the configuration on the RPI so the script (OPC server) run automatically whenever the Raspberry start. i get no result and the OPC won't start.
This is my OPC Server code:

```
import time
import sys
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)

#this ti trigger a fan to check if the script is 
running at the start of the RPI
GPIO.output(17, True)

from opcua import Server
server = Server()

url = "opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:4840"
server.set_endpoint(url)

name = "SCAN_START"
addspace = server.register_namespace(name)

node = server.get_objects_node()

Param = node.add_object(addspace,"Parameters")

ID = Param.add_variable(addspace,"ID",0)
ID.set_writable()

server.start()
GPIO.output(17, False)

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',115200,timeout=0.5)    
while True:
    rcv=ser.read(10).decode('utf-8')
    if (len(rcv)>3):
       ID.set_value(rcv)
```

this is the config of crontab -e

```
@reboot python3 /home/pi/Desktop/test/scan.py
```

PS: the fan starts when the RPI bootsm that means that the script if running when the RPI start but not the OPC server :/

Any guidance or help is very appreciated
Thank you

Comment: i'm still having this problem can any one help please